# How to sort elements of array according to 1) names and 2) age, plus match names and age of array elements in output?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create a program that sorts an array of students, according to 1) name and 2) age.  I managed to get the name sort running okay but it's the sortStage() function that I need help with, that's my function to sort by age.

The first problem is I can't get the names and ages to pair.  The output has names arranged in alphabetical order, yes, but the ages next to them do not correspond with the name.

Second, the sort by age is just not working out, whats displayed are the names as they were in the Sort by name function (sortStnames()).  I would love help with this, sorry it's a noob question.  Thanks in advance.
P.S.  Attached is the entire code to my program, hopefully that will give a better understanding of the program.  The functions in question are in class "ArrayOfRusanguStudent"

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class ZambiaStudents {
  private:
    // Private attribute
    string FNames;
    string Sex;
    string NRC;
    int birthYear;

    public:

    //constructor
    ZambiaStudents(string FNames, string Gender, string NRC, int birthYear) {
        this->FNames = FNames;
        this->Sex = Sex;
        this->NRC = NRC;
        this->birthYear = birthYear;
}

  public:
    // Setters
    void setFNames(string FNames) {
      this->FNames = FNames;
    }

     void setGender(string FNames) {
      this->Sex = Sex;
    }

     void setNRC(string FullNames) {
      this->NRC = NRC;
    }

     void setbirthYear(int birthYear) {
      this->birthYear = birthYear;

    }

    // Getters
    string getFNames() {
      return FNames;
    }
    string getSex() {
      return Sex;
    }
    string getNRC() {
      return NRC;
    }
    int getbirthYear() {
      return birthYear;
    }

  public:
    int calcAge() {
    int age;
    age=2020-getbirthYear();
    return age;
    }
};

class RusanguStudents: public ZambiaStudents {
    private:
        string ID;  //student id
        string AcNo; //account number
        int NumOfCourses; // number of courses

    public:
        RusanguStudents(string ID, string AcNo, int NumOfCourses, string FNames, string Sex, string NRC, int birthYear) : ZambiaStudents(FNames, Sex, NRC, birthYear)
        {
            this->AcNo;
            this->ID;
            this->NumOfCourses;
        }
public:
    // Setters
    void setID(string ID) {
      this->ID = ID;
    }

     void setAcNo(string AcNo) {
      this->AcNo = AcNo;
    }


     void setNumOfCourses(int NumOfCourses) {
      this->NumOfCourses = NumOfCourses;
    }

    // Getters
    string getID() {
      return ID;
    }
    string getAcNo() {
      return AcNo;
    }
    int getNumOfCourses() {
      return NumOfCourses;
    }


    public:
        int calcBill() {
        int bill=500 * getNumOfCourses();
        return bill;
    }
};
class ArrayOfRusanguStudents : public RusanguStudents{


    public:
//student names and age arrays
    string stnames[5];
    int stage[5];
public:
//Constructor
ArrayOfRusanguStudents(string AcNo, string ID, int NumOfCourses, string FNames, string Sex, string NRC, int birthYear) : RusanguStudents(AcNo, ID, NumOfCourses, FNames, Sex,NRC, birthYear){

}


    void assignStudentNames() {
        for (int x = 0; x < (sizeof(stnames) / sizeof(stnames[0])); x++) {
            cout << ("Enter fullname for Student ") << (x << 0) << (": ") << endl;
            string names;
            getline(cin, names);
            this->setFNames(names);
            stnames[x] = this->getFNames();
        }

    }

     void assignStudentage() {
        for (int x = 0; x < (sizeof(stage) / sizeof(stage[0])); x++) {

                //request user input
                cout << ("Enter Year of birth for ") << stnames[x]  << endl;
                int year;
                cin >> year;
                this->setbirthYear(year);


                    //calculate age
                    int age = this->calcAge();
                    //append age to array of student age
                    stage[x] = age;
                }

    }


    void sortStnames(){
        int N = sizeof(stnames)/sizeof(stnames[0]); //Get the array size

        sort(stnames,stnames+N); //Use the start and end like this

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << stnames[i] <<endl;
}
    }
    //student age sorting method

     void sortStage() {

        int n = sizeof(stage)/sizeof(stage[0]);
        sort(stage, stage+n);
        cout << "The Rusangu Student names are ordered according to age: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

       cout  << stnames [i] << " is: " << stage[i] << " years old" << endl;

}
     }
};
int main() {
 

  ArrayOfRusanguStudents ComputerRusanguStudents("I8829", "A34", 5, "Jane Doe", "Female", "220011/23/1", 1998);

  ComputerRusanguStudents.assignStudentNames();

  cout << "The following is list of Students sorted by name: \n" ;
  ComputerRusanguStudents.sortStnames();




  ComputerRusanguStudents.assignStudentage();

  cout << "The following is list of Students sorted by age: \n" ;
  ComputerRusanguStudents.sortStage();

  return 0;


}
```

Comment: Both the problems has one reason This is happening because you have no association with the two things, name, and age. And you are expecting them to print them in such a way so that name has the corresponding age, which is not going to happen in this case. You may try considering a container that comes from STL to store name and age together.

Comment: sort function is undefined & where is bits/stdc++.h
we need full code please :)